# How to get inherited attributes from base class

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get results for GetMethods on Class B, so that it will include methods from a base class A without adding the attribute to the overridden method.

```
Class A
{
    [My]
    public virtual void test(){}
}
Class B , A
{
    public override void test(){}
}

IEnumerable<MethodInfo> typeMethodList = typeof(A).GetMethods().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Any());
   ---Result {Test}

IEnumerable<MethodInfo> typeMethodList = typeof(B).GetMethods().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Any());
   ---Result Empty list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true)`

Answer (score 1):

Either make your attribute inherited or specify explicitly that you want to search ancestors for an attribute.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(Inherited = true)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx

or

```
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> typeMethodList = typeof(B)
    .GetMethods()
    .Any(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(type: typeof(MyAttribute), inherit: false));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130871(v=vs.110).aspx